# the position of parameter of command

Tags: command-line, command, arguments

I think the position of parameter of any command is not fixed.

For example, `cp -r ./abc ./def` and `cp ./abc ./def -r` are the same, `grep -rnH hello .` and `grep hello . -rnH` are the same...

However, today when I was using `ldd`, I found that I was wrong. Because `ldd -r x.so` and `ldd x.so -r` are not the same. The second command gave me an error:

```
ldd: ./-r: No such file or directory
```

Why can't we change the position of parameter of `ldd`?

Comment: A better question would be why `cp` allows an arbitrary order when its documentation doesn't specify it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some GNU utilities silently reorganises the command line parameters so that the options and option-argument comes before the operands. This is not standard behaviour.

Standard-compliant utilities expect options and option-arguments to come first, and when the command line parser finds the first non-option argument, the rest of the arguments are treated as operands:

```
cp -i file1 file2
```

In the above, the first argument is an option while the last two arguments are operands.

```
cp file1 file2 -i
```

The above has three operands, and a non-GNU implementation of `cp` would copy `file1` and `file2` into the directory called `-i` (or give an error message if no such directory existed).  GNU `cp` on the other hand, treats `-i` as an option and asks whether I would want to overwrite `file2` if that file exists.

This behaviour is remedied by setting the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT`:

```
$ cp file1 file2 -i
cp: overwrite 'file2'? n

$ POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 cp file1 file2 -i
cp: target '-i' is not a directory
```

Or you could use `--` to *explicitly* mark the end of options (which would work whether the command parses its options the GNU way or not):

```
$ cp -- file1 file2 -i
cp: target '-i' is not a directory
```

That's something to keep in mind in things like:

```
grep 'PATTERN' *.txt
```

Which with GNU `grep` you need to write:

```
grep -- 'PATTERN' *.txt
```

or

```
grep -e 'PATTERN' -- *.txt
```

In case the `PATTERN` or the name of some of the `.txt` files start with `-`.

Your `ldd` (which on GNU systems is a `bash` script that parses options by hand, not using the GNU `getopt_long()` API) does not parse its command line arguments in the "GNU way", which (IMHO) it's doing correctly.

---

From the GNU documentation of `getopt_long(3)`:

> By default, `getopt()` permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the
>          end.  [...] If the first character of `optstring` is `+` or the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set, then option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument  is  encountered.